# How can we use Private Proxy username and password in Selenium web driver with firefox watir

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir

I am using Watir and Selenium configuration with Firefox my configuration is:-

```
   profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
   profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1
   profile["network.proxy.http"] = ENV['PROXY_IP']
   profile["network.proxy.ssl"] = ENV['PROXY_IP']
   profile["network.proxy.http_port"] = ENV['PROXY_PORT'].to_i
   profile["network.proxy.ssl_port"] = ENV['PROXY_PORT'].to_i

   options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile)
   driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox,  options: options
   browser = Watir::Browser.new  driver
   browser.goto url
```

Comment: I am solving it, With my private proxy account whitelisted the ip, But i want the proper way to do it.